# Printing portion of a map for multiples locations in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-print-layouts

I need to generate .png or .pdf files with a portion of the map that Im currently working on for each object in a shape file. Im working on QGIS3.

I have a shape file with multiple points wich represent the objects that Im interested in. I need to generate one map for each point in the .shp. The map has to be centered on the point and must have an specific scale (1:500). It also has to include other layers that are part of the project.

I was thinking that this could be done with de PyQGIS console because the shape file has more than 500 points and using the Layout Manager would take infinite time.

The image below represent what I need. The point of interest is C143. The map is centered on that point and it also shows objects from other layers that are close to C143 (like text and C145).
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Atlas to create your map. in the Layout manager select Atlas in the Item Proprieties Tab > then select the shapefile with your points as Coverage Layer.

In the Map Item Proprieties > Controlled by Atlas, you can select the option "Fixed scale" and add the scale 1:500 to the map.

This process will create for you an Atlas composed with N pages, one for any geometry of your layer.

In the end, just export as pdf selection *Export Atlas as PDF* from the menus toolbar > Atlas >.

Comment: Thank u! Atlas did exactly what i was looking for.